# How would you make sure that you can't press both the buttons again if the money is under 2900?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When you run the code and press the plan pack button, you could still press the spaceship button. Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Store</legend>
<p id="p"></p>
Spaceship: $2900
   <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick="buy()" id="button" /><br />
Plan pack: $7800
<input type="button" value="Buy" onClick="buy1()" id="button1" /><br />
     </fieldset>
```

JS:

```
var money = 10000;
function buy()  {
money = money - 2900;
$("#p").text("You have $" + money + ".");
if(money < 2900){
$("#button").prop("disabled", true);
}
}
function buy1() {
money = money - 7800;
$("#p").text("You have $" + money + ".");
if(money < 7800){
        $("#button1").prop("disabled", true);
}
}
```

Never mind, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var money = 10000;

if(money < 2900){
 $( "#Your_button" ).prop( "disabled", true );
}

function buy() {
money = money - 2900;
$("#p").text("You have $" + money + ".");
}
```

Use an if statement to set your condition then use [.prop()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/) to disable the button, try giving your button an id so you can select it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
I think it will help you.

```
if($money < 2900){
 $("#button").attr("disabled","disabled");
 }
```

$money is a variable of the I think you can output this using php, mysql

Comment: I have only 5 reputation.

Comment: Well..
I think you are a beginner.

Comment: oh than connect with me facebook.com/aashakil23